# What is "userdel --root?" supposed to do

Tags: linux, options

On a GNU/Linux system, I found the following, (for me very confusing seeming entry) about an option for `userdel` in the German version of its man page:

[image: found this in the German version of <code>man 8 userdel</code>but can't find this option in, say, English]

I'm truly sorry, but I can't really provide you with a translation because a) I don't understand what it means (even with German as mother-tongue) and b) I don't understand what this option is supposed to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the version from my English manpage:

```
 -R, --root CHROOT_DIR
     Apply changes in the CHROOT_DIR directory and use the
     configuration files from the CHROOT_DIR directory.
```

In other words, instead of editing `/etc/passwd` and friends, you're editing `CHROOT_DIR/etc/passwd`.

For example, you might boot a live CD, mount the hard drive as `/mnt`, and then use `-R /mnt` to edit its users.

Comment: after giving this some thought, it finally makes sense :) But the german version is really garbled and confusing... and I really wonder why I didn't find anything on this online up to now (yes I used "userdel --root" and such)